# How to interpret this def that uses a PartialFunction?

Tags: scala

I am still getting used to the concept of PartialFunction in Scala.
I came across the following statement that I can't wrap my head around:

**Update:**
    def msgsToGet: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
is defined in a trait as follows:

```
trait MyActorTrait {
    palindrome: String => def msgsToGet: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
    //After the answers I received, I understand that the "def msgsToGet:      //PartialFunction[Any, Unit]" represents the LHS of an abstract (as yet)     //unimplemented function (no function body yet)

}
```

Now, what does that mean? 
I understand that 'def' denotes a function. In this case, it is a function by name `msgsToGet`.

Then there is a colon (:). Okay, until now, I had always thought "after a colon, is the type, and this is where I am lost.
Okay, is it the same thing as:

```
def msgsToGet(): PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

[A function that takes in no parameters and returns something of type `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`.

`PartialFunction[Any, Unit]` to me somehow looks to me like a return type. But there is no function body. So what is going on here, please?

is this a syntactic sugar for something longer, but readable?

Help me interpret this, please..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is almost the same than

```
def msgsToGet(): PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
```

Scala allows methods without a parameter list (as opposed to one empty parameter list).

In bytecode, these two are the same, but in idiomatic Scala, no parameter list is preferred for methods that are side effect free and especially accessors. Empty parameter list is preferred, ifbthe method is side effecting.

Comment: Just another naive question: How is the function returning a value of type PartialFunction[Any, Unit] if there is no function body?

Comment: Oh, that just means it's an abstract method. Scala doesn't have an abstract keyword. A def/var/val is abstract, if it doesn't have a body.

Comment: You answered my question with a direct answer. @dhg's answer and your answer are both extremely good and eye-openers. well..I am going to mark your question as the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

If there's no function body, then it's an abstract method.  Is it on a trait or an abstract class?  An abstract method, like in Java, says that implementing classes must define the method.

You are correct in your analysis: it is a function called "msgsToGet" that takes no parameters and returns an object of type `PartialFunction[Any, Unit]`.

Here's an example:

```
trait SomeTrait {
  def msgsToGet: PartialFunction[Any, Unit]
}

class SomeClass extends SomeTrait {
  def msgsToGet: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = { 
    case x => println(x)      
  } // a case block is a partial function, so we can return this block from the function
}

val c = new SomeClass
val f = c.msgsToGet    // takes no parameters, returns a partial function
f("hey")               // we can call the partial function, which takes an Any parameter
// prints "hey"
```

Comment: Very good answer. I am going to choose your answer as the right one.

Comment: Very good answer. I promise to upvote your answer once I am able to do so. I did not know that a case block is a partial function, until now.